# change jtable row color

Tags: java, colors, row, cell

I use this code on jtable customize code in custom creation but my selected row not changed please help me for soft this problem

```
    jtablexml = new javax.swing.JTable(){
public Component prepareRenderer ( TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column ){
    Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer,row,column);
    Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row,column);
    if(value.equals(null)){
        component.setBackground(Color.RED);
        component.setForeground(Color.BLACK);        }
    else{
        component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        component.setForeground(Color.BLACK);        }
        jtablexml.setSelectionBackground(Color.GREEN);
    return component;    }
```

};

Comment: You can't invoke a method on a null object. To test for null you use: `if (value == null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but my selected row not changed

Your logic overrides the default selection of the row.

You need an additional check to make sure the row is not highlighted by default:

```
Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer,row,column);

if (!isRowSelected(row))
{
    // add custom highlighting here
}

return component;
```

See [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for other row rendering examples.

Also, don't try to change a property of the table in the renderer.

Comment: why wen i say `** if(value.equals(null)){component.setForeground(Color.red);}  **` dont work and i see this problem `java.lang.NullPointerException`